# reading string after reading string cpp file input

Tags: c++, file-io

So I'm reading from a file and ran into an issue.
I read in an int from the file, and the next line is a string. When I go to store the string into my variable I don't get anything. I get a blank space. I was wondering if there is a way to flush an ifstream so that I can get the next line of the file.

This is how I'm doing the file input:

```
  std::ifstream fin(fileName.c_str());


  if(fin.good()){
    std::getline(fin, this->name);
    fin >> this->weight;
        fin.ignore(1, '\n'); //this was added after a user commented on how to fix it
    std::getline(fin, this->city);
    std::getline(fin, this->destination);
```

Comment: use `fin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` after you read the integer, the previous extraction does not consume the newline.

Comment: Please don't change the original post in a way that makes comments and answers invalid. Add updates to clarify the question or provide additional information, when needed.

Comment: sorry. i will edit it right now.